# How can i pop back from storyboard of framework?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, frameworks

```
let storyboardBundle = Bundle(identifier: "SignUPFramework")

let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "SignIn", bundle: storyboardBundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewcontroller") as! SignInViewcontroller
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I have navigated to storyboard of framework as above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by

```
 let bundle = Bundle(for: SignInViewcontroller.self)
 let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "SignIn", bundle: bundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewcontroller") as! SignInViewcontroller
```

in above snippet instead of passing bundle id i have passed viewcontroller itself.

Answer (score 1):

You own the navigationController. So you can use either [popViewController(animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller) (if you are sure that there is only one view controller you wish to pop), or [popToViewController(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller), or [popToRootViewController(animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller) (if you wish to return to the root).

It does not matter that the storyboard is in a framework. You still own the view hierarchy, the navigation stack and the view controller instance you get from the below line of code

```swift
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "SignIn", bundle: storyboardBundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewcontroller") as! SignInViewcontroller
```

So you can do whatever you want with it in terms of navigation (push it and pop it or present it and dismiss it).
You just need to identify at what point you want to trigger any of these actions.

Comment: I want to pop back from a button of framework storyboard and i have tried pop method but didn't work for me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "pop back from a button of framework storyboard"? Is it a button on the view controller that you instantiated from that framework? If yes then how have you triggered the pop method from its action. Have you added a target action to that button? Can you clarify how things are setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using xib so it will not return action first you should do protocol for callback to view controller then you can use popViewController(animated:).

```
protocol CallBackDelegate: AnyObject {
    func back()
}

//Delegate
weak var delegate:CallBackDelegate?

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.back()
}
```

Now you can use protocol in view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CallBackDelegate {
  func back() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Note :- Confirm delegate variable in cellForRowAtIndexPath i.e.

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: I think you din't get my question. I have asked that i have created a storyboard in framework and pushed from main and now pop is not working.

Comment: @PriyankaVasant - please share me a demo project so that i can help you properly.